# How can i use attributes from table as variables?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, href

I have this code:

```
$emp_id=$_POST['Personal_ID'];    

echo"$emp_id";
$sql="select distinct * from dir, training_list_of_dir, trainings_of_dir
      where dir.personal_id=trainings_of_dir.personal_id and trainings_of_dir.training_tag=training_list_of_dir.training_tag 
      and trainings_of_dir.Personal_ID='$emp_id'";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo"<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>second name</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Training tag</th>
        <th>Training_name</th>
        <th>Date of last training</th>
        <th>Date of next training</th>
    </tr>";     
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>","<a href='some.php'>". $row['Second_name']."</a>", "</td>";
    echo "<td>","<a href='some.php'>".$row['First_name']."</a>" ,"</td>";
    echo "<td>","<a href='some.php'>". $row['Training_tag']. "</a>" ,"</td>";
    echo "<td>","<a href='some.php'>".$row['Training_name']. "</a>" ,"</td>";
    echo "<td>","<a href='some.php'>".$row['Date_of_last_training']. "</a>" ,"</td>";
    echo "<td>","<a href='some.php'>". $row['Date_of_next_training']. "</a>" ,"</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}   

echo "</table>";
```

I would like to use each link in table for something else. For example if I click on training tag it will show me the row in table with the training tag. Or if I click on `Date_of_last_training` it will show me all the people who was on training in this date.

So the problem is, when it shows me table with rows, how can I use name of attribute in  the `where` clause?   For example with the "date of last training", how can I get this date in `where date_of_last_training = $date_of_last_training` (from the table on clicked attribute)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your while loop with this code. And in some.php page code your logic based on the type

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='some.php'>". $row['Second_name']."</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='some.php'>".$row['First_name']."</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='some.php?type=traintag&tag=".$row['Training_tag']."'>". $row['Training_tag']. "</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='some.php?type=trainname&tname=".$row['Training_name']."'>".$row['Training_name']. "</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='some.php?type=lasttrain&date=".$row['Date_of_last_training'].">".$row['Date_of_last_training']. "</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='some.php?type=nexttrain&date=".$row['Date_of_next_training']."'>". $row['Date_of_next_training']. "</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is sql injection vulnerability (security problem) in answer I am giving.  This is only as simple answer.  Please do not use in internet.

in your php, change anchor to this:
    echo "" .
     "" . 
      $row['Training_tag'] .
     "" .
     "";

this will create link like: `http://.../training_tag.php?q=sometag`

do the same thing for other links.

in training_tag.php

```
$q = $_GET['q'];

// replace ?? with correct values
$query = "select * from ?? where ?? = '$q'";

// run your query etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do that with jquery. Get the table name by clicking table field using

```
$('table tr th').click(function(){

    $table = $( this ).text();
});
```

and pass this value and getresponce using ajax.

Comment: cloud you help me with it? i dont know work with it. after the $  can i give name of attribute? and the "function" is what will happen? and "text" mean what? where can i add this part of code?